# Using double * or short * in C DLL, what to use in C# with pinvoke

Tags: c, pointers, dll, pinvoke

I have the following struct in a C DLL:

```
struct foo
{
      double *x;
      short  *y;
}
```

The c# app that calls the DLL:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class foo
{
        public ? x;
        public ? y;
}
```

I understand that I should use IntPtr if I have an int*,  but can't find equivalent for short* and double *.

On the C side, I am using the short * to allocate an array of shorts, the double * for array of doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all unmanaged pointers in C# are represented using `IntPtr`. It's called `IntPtr` not because it's an analogue to `int *`, but rather because it is an integer of "pointer" size (in contrast to `Int32` and `Int64`, which are integers of 32- and 64-bits respectively). Its size is platform dependent.

To get the value of `x[0]`, for example, you'd do

```
double[] arr = new double[1];
Marshal.Copy(f.x, arr, 0, 1);
```

To read `*y`, you'd do

```
short val = Marshal.ReadInt16(f.y);
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear about how I want to use the pointers on the C side.  I've added that in the last line of my post.

Comment: I think I understand...so a  pointer is a pointer, doesn't matter if it is an int*, short*, double*,char* etc...they are all the same size.  And I assume they the same size in the DLL and C, but if I'm compiling a 64bit app, I should use Int64?

Comment: Yes, a pointer is a pointer (in C, they can all be cast to `void *` and back). `IntPtr` is automatically the right size (32 bits for a 32-bit app, 64 bits for a 64-bit app); that's what it means to be 'pointer sized'. Note that you can't link a 32-bit DLL to a 64-bit app or vice versa.